# SQL - select a given user's conversations from messages table of social network database?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, relational-database

i want to select all users a given user had a conversation with displaying the latest message in that conversation.
This is my table:
[image: messages table]

for example: if i want to select user2 conversations, the query must only return user1 and user3 *(since they are the only ones who have a conversation with user1)* and only return the last message in each conversation.

[image: the result should only contain the highlighted rows]

I made a table-valued function that I intended to select the desired results from, it was like this:

```
CREATE function [dbo].[all_pm] ( @u nvarchar(20) )
returns table
as
return
(
select src as [with] from msg where id in
(select id from msg where src=@u or [des]=@u) and src <> @u
union 
select des as [with] from msg where id in
(select id from msg where [des]=@u or src=@u) and [des] <> @u
)
/*
select * from all_pm('user2')
*/
```

but it only gets me the users that had a conversation with the given user and not the latest message in their conversations. I understand that I did only select the **src** and **des** in the code but if select **msg** too, it would show me all the messages in those conversations.

hope you guys can help me; I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Reasons not to use images are [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/92546).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `row_number()` and some additional logic:

```
select m.*
from (select msg,
             row_number() over (partition by (case when @u = src then des else src end)
                                order by date_time desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from msg
      where @u in (src, des)
     ) m
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: this solved a part of my problem which made life a bit easier for me, thank you very much! can you please explain to me how does it exactly work? if you don't mind, of course

Comment: @EnassHussien . . . https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  ORDER BY created_at DESC at the end and close the whole query in ().

Next time try to copy and paste the code instead of insterting an image of it